# Managing extlinux configuration file under Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, debian, configuration-managment

The things under Debian/Ubuntu [used to be](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/extlinux-debian.html):

> On Debian or Ubuntu, if you make changes to files like `/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf` directly, they'll be overwritten.
>
> The configuration files are regenerated by a program called `extlinux-update`, which runs automatically every time you update your kernel.

The approach has it own pros and cons, however, with [`extlinux-update` gone for goods from Debian/Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/743802/how-to-boot-linux-with-extlinux),  how would one maintain the extlinux configuration files then?

Here is one I use, based on the `linux.cfg` file generated by `extlinux-update`:

```
label UbuntuMate1804
        menu label UbuntuMate ^Bionic, kernel 4.15.0-20-generic
        menu default
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
        append initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic root=/dev/root ro
```

All I did is just to change the `label` and `menu label` and all the rest has been taken care of for me.

Now, without `extlinux-update`, does it mean that I need to remember to update my `/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf` file every time I updated my kernel? Is manual editing the only option? Then how about when the kernel is automatically updated?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel packages in Debian have a practice of leaving convenience symlinks to the installed kernel in the locations `vmlinuz` and `vmlinuz.old` for current and the preceding one, respectively. Likewise for `initrd.img` and `initrd.img.old`. So you can simply reference those paths from `extlinux.conf` and always access the latest two versions at boot time.

The file `/etc/kernel-img.conf` can be used to customize this behavior further. For example, if you install extlinux into /boot, then you can have the symlinks into boot by adding the line `link_in_boot=yes`.

The relevant manual page is `linux-update-symlinks(1)`.

Comment: I'm afraid `/etc/kernel-img.conf` has nothing to do with `extlinux.conf`, bro.

Comment: @xpt please re-read the whole sentence. Are you aware of how the kernel packages create symlinks to the last and the next-to-last version, does it need to be explained further?

Comment: No, as you've totally lost me, so don't bother.